# On finding $2$ numbers in a set such that one divides the other.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility

Here is the original problem

> Let $p > 5$ be a prime number and $$X = \{p - n^2| n \in \mathbb{N}, n^2 < p\}.$$ Prove that $X$ contains two distinct elements $x, y$ such that $x \neq 1$ and $x$ divides $y$.

I found solutions to this but they involved the use of floor function$\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$.
I am very much a beginner to number theory, and I wish solutions that avoid the use of these and modular arithmetic. What I essentially know is theorems in divisibility, and some that relate to primes.

For a special note, one tends to conjecture on the first few observations that $p - (n')^2\ |\ p - 1$, but this fails for $23$, for example, where $n'$ is the greatest value of $n$.
So now, okay, the hope to prove that conjecture is gone, but still I hoped that $p - (n')^2$, would have to do some thing with the proof.
But again, one can see the example for $17$, where $p - (n')^2 = 1$, which is not as what the question asks. ($x \neq 1$)

Now how should I relate the elements in the original set so that one divides the other, I don't know.
I provided what my thoughts were; though I have no idea how to exploit them, or how to create another stream of algebra that says something more about the problem. I provided, from my view, what **not** works for the problem.

Helping is welcome, and thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a reason why number theory isn't taught in third grade: for professional mathematics, you need professional tools. What would you think of a statement like "I'm new to rocket technology, and I wouldn't want to use anything but a stone axe!"?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I got this problem in a book, which I am studying now. I read the book systematically, so what I learnt till now I mentioned in my post, and this problem troubled me a lot, so decided to ask a question. Because I got stumped here and could really not proceed, I provided what I know so that answerers have an idea what solutions I can understand.

Comment: @BookOfFlames  i don't undersatnd why you put the question as a spoiler!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I hope that I have fixed to make it more clear on your suggestion!

Comment: yes now its fine!unfortunately i have no idea to solve problem ,+1 for your efforts

Comment: Does someone has an idea?

Comment: I claim that for $p>13$ in $X$ there is at least one prime number

Comment: @Raffaele Your claim fails for $31.$

Comment: @BookOfFlames Ouch! The shortest conjecture in math history...

Comment: You should learn what the floor function is as it makes the proof much easier to read, which can help with understanding (mainly because there is less that you need to hold in your head).

Comment: @CalvinLin I know what a floor function is, but I don't what to use it because that way was not how the problem was meant to be solved, according to my book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity of notation, let $P$ be the largest integer smaller than or equal to $ \sqrt{p-2}$. This is the only use of the floor function, which you can otherwise ignore by just memorizing the definition of $P$.

---

We want to find a $n, m$ such that $ p -n^2 \mid p - m^2 $, subject to $ 1 \leq m < n \leq \sqrt{ p - 2 }$, or that $ 1 \leq m < n \leq P$.

Notice that $ p - n^2 \mid p - m^2 \Rightarrow p-n^2 \mid (p-m^2)  - (p-n^2) = n^2-m^2 = (n-m)(n+m)$.

Wishful thinking: It would be very nice if we had $ p-n^2  = n+m$. If so, the divisibility result is immediate.
What can we do to help ensure this could happen? What issues might arise (and can we fix them)?

Firstly, since $n + m < 2P$ is "small", let's aim to make $ p-n^2$ small. What's the smallest it can be?

> With $n = P,$ we get $p - P^2$.

Secondly, if $ p -n^2 < n$, then $m$ will be negative.

> Well, in this case, we have $ p -n^2 = n - m$, so we just need to modify our wishful thinking slightly to $ p - n^2 = n-m$ or $n+m$.

Finally, can we always have $ p - n^2 = n-m$ or $n + m$?

> Since $ 0 < m < P$, the only requirement is that $ 0 < |p - P^2 -P | < P $.

(Fill in the gaps, use the fact that $p>5$ is prime.)
Verify that this holds true unless $ p  = (P+1)^2 + 1 $ for some odd $P \geq 3$.
For this case, setting $ n = P, m = 1$ gives us $ p - P^2 = 2P + 2, p - 1 = P^2 + 2P + 1$, so $ \frac{p-m^2}{p-n^2} = \frac{P+1}{2}$ which is an integer as $P$ is odd, so we are done.

Corollary: $n = P$ always works.

---

Note

- You could have guessed at the conclusion $n=P$ by checking small (but large enough) cases and listing out all of the $(n, m)$ that worked. You came close to this, but didn't properly deal with the $p = k^2+1$ scenario.
- With this guess, it's direct to prove that it works (which likely is similar to the above).

Comment: Very thanks! But why did you consider taking $\sqrt{p-2}$?

Comment: @BookOfFlames Because of the conditions in the problem. We need $p - n^2 > 1$, which gives us $ p-2 \geq n^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{p-2} \geq n$. That's all that you were missing (which was what I meant by "You came close to this, but didn't properly deal ...").

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old post, but I find it seriously difficult to go with Sir Titu's number theory textbook. Do you recommend it for beginners like me?

Comment: @BookOfFlames Depends on how much you're willing to work for it. There's always going to be some amount of struggling as you figure things out for the first time, and you should preserve through it. If you can't solve it, avoid reading the entire solution and just go line by line and ask yourself "Why did they do that? Why didn't I think of it? Do I know the material well enough to have done this?"

Comment: Thanks! But I am beginner to competitive mathematics itself, so I think of reading it in this order: Go for the beginning problems for the first reading, then the next problems in the second reading, and complete in the third reading of the book. Though there are at times set theory involved that I don't understand, but I might at least have something I can learn. Should I go for this kind of reading? (because I for now completely feel like giving up on the book when I solve it problem by problem, exercise by exercise.)

Comment: @BookOfFlames If you're new to Number Theory, then you might need another more basic book, or at least look up other references. Don't be afraid to look at multiple sources. If there is a specific topic that you need help with, do a search for olympiad training notes to see if the exist, and if they provide more details for you to work through. Part of what you need to do is to find material that is of a suitable difficulty for you to engage with.